# How to call the the Browser tab using Windows Services

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

Am Create the Windows Service Application from that I need to open a Browser tab/window. Amusing VS 2017 and Windows 10.

Comment: Are you trying to launch a browser?

Comment: Yes, I need to open any of the browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to start the browser and open a web site you can use :

```
     try
        {
            using (Process myProcess = new Process())
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

I Just tried this and it's working. You can use Enviroment variables for the path of IE.

Comment: I tried with this Process.Start but it is not working. Someone said that this will not work in windows 10, then also I tried but still not working. You have any Suggestion other then this to open any link or empty browser.